# Redirect old product links

Tags: redirect

I have transfered a webshop with 1000 products and I have keept the same ID´s

Is there an easy way to redirect the old product links to the news urls ?

The structure of the old link is like this:
shopexd.asp?id=341&bc=no

And the new url is
product.php?id_product=341

I hope you can save me for some time redirect each link manually :)

Comment: Which webserver? Server or client side? Support for regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use url rewriting, so that the old url when accessed will be converted on the fly by the webserver to use the new script.

You per example can do this with mod_rewrite on apache webservers http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

If the url are hardcoded and you want to convert them, i suggest you to use a tool to remplace them using regular expressions (like [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed))

Comment: The URL´s are created dynamic. I have mod_rewrite activated for SEO friendly URLS on the new webshop.

Comment: If url are created dynamicaly, can't you modify the url generation method in you webapp sources? Or do you want to redirect links that you can't modify  (per example in a forum post, someone put a link to the website use the old url style and you want this url to still be valid)